# Python POST requests missing

Tags: python

I have a cron job running my Py script every 15m. The script works in a way to pull the last records 15m back from the DB and push them to external API.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
try:
    with db.cursor() as cur:
        query = """
        select idfa, idfv, product_id from ios_purchase where purchase_date >= %s and purchase_date <= %s
        """
        cur.execute(query, data)
        for row in cur:
            params['advertising_id'] = row[0]
            params['developer_device_id'] = row[1]
            params['product_id'] = row[2]
            params['price'] = 3.99
            r = requests.post('https://xxx.xxx.io/v0/p', auth=(config['xxx']['API_KEY'], ''),
                              params=params)
            print(date_end, r.url, r.status_code, r.content)
except:
    print("db error purchase")
    sys.exit(1)
```

When I try to manually run a query on the DB, I get the expected number of records.

Upon checking the logs however, sometimes happens that not all requests went through as I have for example 5 records in the DB to push, but only 4 requests in the log.

I am usually a PHP dev so I don't know whether this is some "expected" Python issue with multiple requests in the short time span or something?

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know not all requests succeeded?

Comment: Because as I said in example, I have 5 records to push in the DB, but actually push 4 of them. I see that because the logs for the cron job show 4 requests, not 5

Comment: Are you logging the database query? Is it guaranteed that the two dats in `data` do indeed cover the intended period (that contains 5 records)?

Comment: The first comment states that if the last post requests fails, there will not be a print statement, hence you'll only see 4 print outputs, while there have been 5 attempts (of which the first 4 succeeded).

Comment: It would be good for the future to log the actual error as well: `except Exception as exc:\n print("db error purchase:", exc)`.

Comment: What do you mean? One `print()` is inside try, other one is under except. Doesn't that mean that something should be printed in any case?